# How to obtain the variance of a chi-squared distribution with Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm new to Mathematica and would like to show that for $x_1, ..., x_k$ independent, standard normal random variables the variance of the sum of their squares, i.e., $var(\sum_{i=1}^kx_k^2)$, is equal to $2k$.

Therefore, I implemented the following:

```
x= NormalDistribution[mx,stdx];

Variance[TransformedDistribution[Sum[a*a,{i,i_max}], {Distributed[a, x]}]];
```

The result is not `2i_max`. However, the output is:

```
2(2mx^2stdx^2i_max^2 + stdx^4i_max^2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `i_max` is not a valid variable name.  Use `imax`, instead.

Comment: The result is the same only with imax replaced by i_max.

Comment: Your code only has a single random variable ($a$) so the result is correct for that.  You are essentially getting the variance of $imax * a$.  What you probably intend (because you state the answer is $2k$) is that you have $k$ independent and identically distributed random variables.  Therefore you should use `a[i]` instead of `a`.

Comment: Then, the result is 0. Or do I also need to change something inside “Distributed“ ?

Comment: Take a look at `Table[{n,
Variance[TransformedDistribution[Sum[a[i]^2, {i, n}], Table[a[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], {i, n}]]]}, {n, 2, 10}] // TableForm`.

Comment: Thanks! That produces the expected output for the values 2 to 10. Is there a way to also achieve a symbolic result, i.e., 2k ?

Comment: `var[k_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, k]` where `seq` is the sequence provided by @JimB Alternatively, you can do a proof by induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the ways given in the comments a more direct symbolic approach is to use moment generating functions (or characteristic functions).  One obtains the mgf for the square of a unit normal and the mgf of the sum of n independent and identically distributed random variables is the individual mgf raised to the n-th power.  Then find the variance from that resulting mgf.

```
(* Determine moment generating function for a single random variable *)
mgf = MomentGeneratingFunction[TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]], t];

(* First raw moment of the sum of n iid random variables *)
m1 = (D[mgf^n, t]) /. t -> 0;

(* Second raw moment *)
m2 = (D[mgf^n, {t, 2}]) /. t -> 0;

(* Find variance *)
variance = m2 - m1^2 // Expand
(* 2 n *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works. I'd like to calculate now the variance of $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i(x_i+y_i)$ with $k$  independent and identically distributed random variables  $x_i, y_i$. Therefore, I changed your first line to: `mgf = MomentGeneratingFunction[TransformedDistribution[x*(x+y), { x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s1],y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s2]}], t];`. Is that correct? The solution is, unfortunately, not such a short expression and contains different terms with "MomentGeneratingFunction".

Comment: @user82859 - your comment is not a clarification of your original question but rather a whole new question. This should be posted as a new and separate question. You should link back here for context. You should also upvote this answer and, since it apparently answers your original question, accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Bob, you’re right! I upvoted your answer. Thanks again, this really helped. I try to adjust to the stackexchange standards as fast as possible. :-)

Comment: This is @JimB answer and you have not upvoted it yet since the count only shows `1` which is mine.

Comment: It says “ Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.”

Answer (score 3):

Using proof by induction

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Each individual term of the sum of squares of i.i.d. **standard normal** variates (i.e., `NormalDistribution[0, 1]`) are distributed `ChiSquareDistribution[1]`

```
TransformedDistribution[x^2,
 x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]

(* ChiSquareDistribution[1] *)
```

The problem is then just the sum of `k` i.i.d. variates each with distribution `ChiSquareDistribution[1]`

The distribution of the sum of two of these variates is

```
TransformedDistribution[z1 + z2,
  {z1 \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[1],
   z2 \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[1]}]

(* ChiSquareDistribution[2] *)
```

Consequently, **assuming** that the sum of `k - 1` of these variates is distributed `ChiSquareDistribution[k - 1]` then the sum of `k` variates would be

```
TransformedDistribution[z1 + z2,
 {z1 \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[k - 1],
  z2 \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[1]}]

(* ChiSquareDistribution[k] *)
```

This is consistent with the assumption; so if it is true for `k - 1` it is also true for `k`. Since the assumption is already shown to be true for `k = 2` then by induction it is true for all `k >= 2`

The [`Variance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html) is then

```
Variance[ChiSquareDistribution[k]]

(* 2 k *)
```

Comment: +1 This answer is more general (a very good thing) and doesn't require "special knowledge" about moment generating functions.