# How to obtain the variance of $\sum_{i=1}^mx_i(x_i+y_i)$ with Mathematica?

Tags: distributions

I'd like to symbolically calculate the variance of $\sum_{i=1}^mx_i(x_i+y_i)$ with Mathematica, where $x_1, ... x_m$ and $y_1, ... y_m$ are independent, standard normal random variables.

In a previous post I already got an excellent answer how to calculate the variance of $\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^2$ symbolically with Mathematica (Reference: [How to obtain the variance of a chi-squared distribution with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258570/how-to-obtain-the-variance-of-a-chi-squared-distribution-with-mathematica/258575#258575)).

I'd like to apply the answer of that question now to the expression above. Therefore, I use the following code in Mathematica:

```
(* Determine moment generating function for the expression x*(x+y) *)
mgf = MomentGeneratingFunction[TransformedDistribution[x*(x+y), { x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s1],y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s2]}], t];

(* First raw moment of the sum of n iid random variables *)
m1 = (D[mgf^n, t]) /. t -> 0;

(* Second raw moment *)
m2 = (D[mgf^n, {t, 2}]) /. t -> 0;

(* Find variance *)
variance = m2 - m1^2 // Expand
```

The solution is, unfortunately, not a short expression and contains different terms with "MomentGeneratingFunction". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: When I run your code I get 2 n s1^4 + n s1^2 s2^2. Perhaps quit the kernel and try again... (Evaluation->Quit Kernel->Local)

Comment: If your interest is in standard normal distributions, you should set `s1` and `s2` to 1.

Comment: @JimB Yes, thanks!

Comment: @bills True, now it seems to work. Thanks a lot! Let's hope it's correct. A proof by hand is in progress ..

Comment: A proof can depend on what you already know to be true.  Another approach for your two questions is that the variance of the sum of independent random variables is  the sum of the variances:  `n Variance[
  TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]]` and `n Variance[TransformedDistribution[x (x + y), {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}]]`.

Comment: Thanks, JimB! Much appreciated. That‘s an awesome forum here.